# how to configure environment variable or http_proxy for a prometheus scrape_configs job?

Tags: http, prometheus, http-proxy

I want to use prometheus to monitor hosts on the unreachable network.
Now I have a suqid-server to link two networks.
On prometheus server exec "export http_proxy=suqid-host:port", I can get metrics info form target hosts.
But I want to configure the http_proxy only for one scrape_configs's job, not global.
What should i do？

Thanks.